# Cannot set outlook message body on compose mode using appleScript

Tags: applescript, applescript-objc

I am trying to get and set outlook message body on compose mode.setting value does not work. is something wrong with script ?. but get value is working fine.

```
activate application "Microsoft Outlook"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Microsoft Outlook"
          get value of static text 1 of group 1 of UI element 1 of scroll area 4 of splitter group 1 of window 1
          set value of static text 1 of group 1 of UI element 1 of scroll area 4 of splitter group 1 of window 1 to "sample text"       

    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using UI scripting unless there is no other way.

This script shows you how to set the message body.

```
tell (current date) to get (it's month as integer) & "-" & day & "-" & (it's year as integer)
set MyDay to the result as text
set Mytitle to "Daily Email - " as text
set Mytitle to Mytitle & MyDay

tell application "Microsoft Outlook"

    set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:Mytitle}
    make new recipient at newMessage with properties {email address:{name:"Name", address:"test@example.com"}}
    #make new cc recipient at newMessage with properties {email address:{name:"Name", address:"test@example.com"}}

    --- SET EMAIL BODY USING PLAIN TEXT ---
    set plain text content of newMessage to "This is just a TEST."

    open newMessage
end tell
```